# Scheduled method in a standalone application in spring

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a method which needs to be executed every day at 07:00.
For that matter I created a bean with the method and annotated it with `@Scheduled(cron="0 0 7 * * ?")`.
In this bean I crated a `main` function - which will initialize the spring context, get the bean and invoke the method ( at least for the first time ), like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(args[0]);
    SchedulerService schedulerService = context.getBean(SchedulerService.class);
    schedulerService.myMethod();
}
```

This works just fine - but just once.
I think I understand why - It's because the `main` thread ends - and so is the spring context so even though `myMethod` is annotated with `@Scheduled` it wont work.

I thought of a way to pass this - meaning don't let the `main` thread die, perhaps like this:

```
while (true){
   Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
}
```

That's how, I think, the application context will remain and so is my bean.

Am I right?

Is there a better way to solve this?

I'm using spring 3.1.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thread should stay active until any non-daemon threads are alive. If you have a `<task:annotation-driven/>` tag in your application then Spring should start up a executor with a small pool of non-daemon threads for you and the main application should not terminate.

The only thing that you will need to do is to register a shutdown hook also to ensure a cleanup when the VM ends.

`context.registerShutdownHook()`

Comment: Thanks!
I didn't use the `while` loop and it's working just great!

Answer (score 1):

The join method is ideal for this:

```
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.warn("Interrupted", e);
    }
```

Alternatively, here's the old school wait method:

```
    final Object sync = new Object();
    synchronized (sync) {
        try {
            sync.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.warn("Interrupted", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,
I tried to read about the `join()` method - but couldn't understand - that means that the current thread waits until which thread is finished?

Comment: This is a bad example of the join method.
Lets say the main thread starts a sub thread to do some work.  Then the main thread finishes.  In this case you don't want the main thread to finish until the other thread has finished, as if the main thread finishes, it means the process will finish.  Therefore, the main thread can join onto the sub thread, then the main thread will wait until the sub thread finishes.  Once the sub thread finishes, the main thread will resume, and pick up after the join call.

Comment: Thanks, so that means that the main thread will be finished sometime - when all the threads it created are finished. 
That's not what I'm looking for - I simply don't want the main thread to ever end.

Comment: In that case, the sync.wait() make more sense for you.