# Java stand-alone application as Scheduled tast executor with Spring

Tags: java, spring, periodic-processing

I need to create stand alone application only for processing periodical tasks.
Currently I did it by using Spring with @Scheduled tasks, but I don't like while(true) construction.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
    while (true) ;
}
```

Is there a better solution, like sleeping current thread?

Comment: quartz is a good scheduler... you may want to take a look.

Comment: I already have spring oriented code and it is quite straight forward to use @Scheduled annotation on tasks/

Comment: I found good answer for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176923/scheduled-method-in-a-standalone-application-in-spring